# Mysql Connection, how to request data correctly?

Tags: android, mysql

I'm trying to follow this tutorial in order to connect to an external database with android:

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database

However, I seem to receive two different errors when viewing the php / mysql connection code directly
and through logcat.

If I look at it through a browser, it comes up with the orange php error saying:

```
Undefined index: year


Found on line 6 with  .$_REQUEST['year'].
```

If i debug the app and look at the logcat output, it seems to give a half error:

```
E/log_tag (  403): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text m
ust start with '[' at character 6 of
```

On the php page, below the error, Json prints off the tables correctly, and echoing mysql errors are fine.

Can anyone help with the implementation of this function `$_REQUEST` please? (If that is the problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output comes from the http request must be a well formed json string.
Obviously a PHP error like an Undefined index can break the json string and makes it unparsable by java.

You need to rid off the notice, for istance:

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['year']) && $_REQUEST['year'] == 'foo'){
  //Do query and output back the json array
}
?>
```

BTW `$_REQUEST` is not a function. Is a superglobal associative array where all request variables (GET/POST/COOKIE) are stored.

Comment: Thanks for the help, errors cleared, still working on connection.